# Understanding Perl variables

Tags: perl

I just joined a project and I'm supposed to understand the previous person's scripts.

I am new to Perl. Can someone please tell me what this statement would mean?

```
my $name = $1;
```

How can a variable be assigned a value `$something`? I tried to print it but it gives me an error message.

Comment: If $1 was assigned a value previously, like 'Frank', then you could assign $name =$1.

Comment: Perl comes with [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 5):

The `$1` is a special variable used to return the first capture group in a regex.

For example you might see something like:

```
my $string = 'this is an example of 34 a match! 99 foo bar';

$string =~ /\d+\s(.*?)(\d+)/;
```

In this case the first captured group (`a match!`) will be stored in the variable `$1`, and the second (`99`) in `$2`.

```
print "first capture group = $1\nsecond capture group = $2\n";
```

You might want to reassign these:

```
my $match = $1;
my $number = $2;
```

Comment: To add to that, you could have a $2 if your regex has two () in it like /\d+(.*)(.*)/.

Answer (score 0):

Beside @fugu said, I want to express more. When you used `$3`, there will be nothing in `$3`, because in that example, only match 2 times.  In perl, many variables are used, like `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, there are `$_` for current variables in the loop; `$_[0]` , `$_[1]`,.. for variables in the function; `ARGV[0]`.. for argv of the script, and so on. Use these to save you manual work.